# WPF ComboBox: Bind ItemsSource to List and Two-way Bind selected value to ViewModel Property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

This is my first go 'round with WPF bindings of this nature so I'm sure I'm doing something silly.

### Background / Setup

I have the following:

- A ViewModel (MainWindowViewModel)
- A bound Datacontext

  - in the `Window` definition, `DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}"`
- In the viewmodel, a list:

  - `readonly List<string> _sqlServerChoices = new List<string>{"DEV", "SPDEV", "SPSQL", "SQL2008"};`
- A viewmodel property exposing the list:

  - `public List<string> SqlServerChoices{get { return _sqlServerChoices; }}`
- A `ComboBox` for selecting the SQL Server
- A property called "Settings" which is a custom type, `UploaderSettings`, which has collections of database settings, sharepoint settings, etc.
- A property called `SqlServerHasBeenEntered`, which is a boolean that returns whether the
- A text box that should be enabled or disabled based on whether a SQL

### The Goal

- I would like to have the choices for the items in the combobox (the ItemsSource) to be set to the list of SQL Servers. This appears to work fine.
- I would like the selected element of the list to be a two-way binding to the Settings.DatabaseSettings.SqlServer property on the ViewModel.
- When this property is updated, I would like to fire OnPropertyChanged for the SqlServerHasBeenEntered property.
- I would like to have the text box enabled or disabled based on whether the SqlServerHasBeenEntered property is true or false.

### The Problem

The binding appears to be failing silently. I see the combo box items, but when I select them, nothing is changing and it appears the onpropertychanged event handler isn't being called.

### The Code So Far

The ComboBox XAML definition:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SqlServerChoices}" 
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Settings.DatabaseSettings.SqlServer, 
                                Mode=TwoWay, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }">
```

The Boolean value for whether or not the SQL Server field has text:

```
public bool SqlServerHasBeenEntered
{
    get
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.DatabaseSettings.SqlServer);
    }
}
```

The Property changing handler:

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: did you put the breakpoint in setter of Settings.DatabaseSettings.SqlServer and see if it hits when you select value in combo? also i am assuming Settings.DatabaseSettings.SqlServer is not automatic property?

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property to bind to your `Settings.DatabaseSettings.SqlServer` property (instead of `SelectedValue`). Then add the `IsEnabled` property binding:

```
<ComboBox IsEnabled="{Binding SqlServerHasBeenEntered}" ... />
```

Finally, you need to call `OnPropertyChanged("SqlServerHasBeenEntered");` from wherever you can when you want it to update. (This *can* be called from another related property setter that gets updated at a certain time, or just from any method).

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify: I have another text box whose IsEnabled property is bound in the way you mention. What seems to not be happening is the property seems to not be updating on the change of the combo box.

Comment: Have you now used the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property? Is `Settings.DatabaseSettings.SqlServer` of the *same* type as the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property? Does it have both a getter and a setter?